# How do you add a column with row totals in DPLYR when the first variable is not numeric?

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to add a column which consists of the calculated row totals where the first variable is not numeric.

Data:

```
 branch Pass_test_equity Fail_test_equity no_dependent_equity
  <fct>             <dbl>            <dbl>               <int>
1 branc1              230               47                 620
2 branc2             1460              201                1681
3 branc3              875              140                1533
```

Expected Output:

```
ranch Pass_test_equity Fail_test_equity no_dependent_equity Total
  <fct>             <dbl>            <dbl>               <int> <int> 
1 branc1              230               47                 620 897
2 branc2             1460              201                1681 3342
3 branc3              875              140                1533 2548
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using mutate rowwise over a subset of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450723/using-mutate-rowwise-over-a-subset-of-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try:

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Sum = select_if(., is.numeric) %>%
           rowSums)
```

As @akrun mentioned, another option is to use `reduce` instead of `rowSums`:

```
df %>% 
      mutate(Sum = select_if(., is.numeric) %>%
      reduce("+"))
```

Result:

```
  branch Pass_test_equity Fail_test_equity no_dependent_equity  Sum
1 branc1              230               47                 620  897
2 branc2             1460              201                1681 3342
3 branc3              875              140                1533 2548
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text ="branch Pass_test_equity Fail_test_equity no_dependent_equity
                 branc1              230               47                 620
                 branc2             1460              201                1681
                 branc3              875              140                1533",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Another opiton is `df %>% mutate(Sum = select_if(., is.numeric) %>% reduce("+"))`  The `+` would be inside backquotes

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added it to my answer :).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `apply`:

```
df$Total <- apply(df[, -1], 1, sum)
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Total = Pass_test_equity + Fail_test_equity + no_dependent_equity)
```

Replace `df` with your dataframe

Comment: Better than `apply(.. sum)` would be `rowSums(df[,-1])`