# Passing list of variable names to custom function with mutate

Tags: r, dictionary, tidyverse, dplyr

I am trying to perform a function over each row and create a new column that considers multiple columns using `tidyverse` , I was initially using `rowwise()`  but that was very slow. I want the list of columns into my custom function be a variable, but I can't get it to work unless I explicitly list the variable names. For example, this works:

```
low_risk_codes <- c(0,1,10)
vars <- c("V1", "V2")
m <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3)
classify_low_risk_drug <- function(...){
  t <- cbind(...)
  return(apply(t, 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x %in% low_risk_codes), 1, 0)))
}

as.data.frame(m) %>%
  mutate(val4 = classify_low_risk_drug(V1, V2))
```

But if I want it to evaluate using the column input as vars :

```
as.data.frame(m) %>% 
  mutate(val4 = classify_low_risk_drug(vars))
```

But I can't get it to work even if I include `!!`, what am I missing?!

Also any suggestions for how to do this with `map` instead are also appreciated!

Comment: In. the first. one, you are. passing unquoted

Comment: Also, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450723/using-mutate-rowwise-over-a-subset-of-columns?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it will do what you want, but I need to qualify it (a lot). First, FYI, I am still wrapping my mind around NSE in R but I find [this vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) very helpful.

Related to the solution, I tried to speed up the function by avoiding `rowwise()` or `apply()`. It should be quicker with `rapply()`/`rowSums()` but I did not benchmark it. It may run into issues with very large data because `rowSums()` will convert the dataframe into a matrix but that probably wont be a problem. In theory, you should also be able to use select helpers / unquoted variable names / columns positions (if you so dare).

Also, I find it a little quirky that you need to supply the dataframe as the first argument (i.e., as `.`), but there may be a way around that. I am certainly open to anyway that wants to edit this / use this as the base for their solution. Hope this helps / gets you going in the right direction!

```
classify_low_risk_drug <- function(.data, vars, codes, na.rm = FALSE){

  df <- rapply(.data, function(x) x %in% codes, how = "replace")
  as.integer(rowSums(select(df, !!enquo(vars)), na.rm = na.rm) > 0)

  }

as.data.frame(m) %>%
  mutate(val4 = classify_low_risk_drug(., vars = vars, codes = c(0, 1, 10)))
  V1 V2 V3 val4
1  1  4  7    1
2  2  5  8    0
3  3  6  9    0
```

EDIT: you could improve the speed a little bit by avoiding the matrix conversion / using `lapply()` w/ `pmax()`:

```
classify_low_risk_drug2 <- function(.data, vars, codes, na.rm = FALSE){

  as.integer(do.call(pmax, lapply(select(.data, !!enquo(vars)), `%in%`, codes)))

}
```