# Using the R syntax sequence operator ":" within the the sum command with more then 50 columns

Tags: r, syntax

i would like to index by column name within the sum command using the sequence operator.

```
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)

df=data.frame(
  X=c("A","B","C"),
  X.1=c(1,2,3),X.2=c(1,2,3),X.3=c(1,2,3),X.4=c(1,2,3),X.5=c(1,2,3),X.6=c(1,2,3),X.7=c(1,2,3),X.8=c(1,2,3),X.9=c(1,2,3),X.10=c(1,2,3),
  X.11=c(1,2,3),X.12=c(1,2,3),X.13=c(1,2,3),X.14=c(1,2,3),X.15=c(1,2,3),X.16=c(1,2,3),X.17=c(1,2,3),X.18=c(1,2,3),X.19=c(1,2,3),X.20=c(1,2,3),
  X.21=c(1,2,3),X.22=c(1,2,3),X.23=c(1,2,3),X.24=c(1,2,3),X.25=c(1,2,3),X.26=c(1,2,3),X.27=c(1,2,3),X.28=c(1,2,3),X.29=c(1,2,3),X.30=c(1,2,3),
  X.31=c(1,2,3),X.32=c(1,2,3),X.33=c(1,2,3),X.34=c(1,2,3),X.35=c(1,2,3),X.36=c(1,2,3),X.37=c(1,2,3),X.38=c(1,2,3),X.39=c(1,2,3),X.40=c(1,2,3),
  X.41=c(1,2,3),X.42=c(1,2,3),X.43=c(1,2,3),X.44=c(1,2,3),X.45=c(1,2,3),X.46=c(1,2,3),X.47=c(1,2,3),X.48=c(1,2,3),X.49=c(1,2,3),X.50=c(1,2,3),
  X.51=c(1,2,3),X.52=c(1,2,3),X.53=c(1,2,3),X.54=c(1,2,3),X.55=c(1,2,3),X.56=c(1,2,3))
```

Is there a quicker way todo this. The following provides the correct result. However, for large datasets (larger than this one ) it becomes vary laborious to deal with especially when pivot_wider is used and the columns are not created before hand (like above)

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(
  Result_column=case_when(
    X=="A"~ sum(c(X.1,X.2,X.3,X.4,X.5)),
    X=="B"~ sum(c(X.4,X.5)),
    X=="C" ~ sum(c( X.3,    X.4,    X.5,    X.6,    X.7,    X.8,    X.9,    X.10,   X.11,   X.12,   X.13,   X.14,   X.15,   X.16,   
                    X.17,   X.18,   X.19,   X.20,   X.21,   X.22,   X.23,   X.24,   X.25,   X.26,   X.27,   X.28,   X.29,   X.30,   
                    X.31,   X.32,   X.33,   X.34,   X.35,   X.36,   X.37,   X.38,   X.39,   X.40,   X.41,   X.42,X.43,  X.44,
                    X.45,   X.46,   X.47,   X.48,   X.49,   X.50,   X.51,   X.52,   X.53,   X.54,   X.55,   X.56))))  %>% dplyr::select(Result_column)
```

The following is the how it would be used when using "select" syntax, which is  that i would like to use. However, does not provide correct numerical solution. One can shorter the code by ~50 entries, by using a sequence operator ":".

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(
  Result_column=case_when(
    X=="A"~ sum(c(X.1:X.5)),
    X=="B"~ sum(c(X.4:X.5)),
    X=="C" ~ sum(c(X.3:X.56)))) %>% dplyr::select(Result_column)
```

below is a related question, however, not the same because what is needed is not a column that starts with "X" but rather a  sequence.
[Using mutate rowwise over a subset of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450723/using-mutate-rowwise-over-a-subset-of-columns)

EDIT:
the provided code (below) from cnbrowlie  is correct.

```
df %>%  mutate(
  Result_column=case_when(
    X=="A"~ sum(c(X.1:X.5)),
    X=="B"~ sum(c(X.4:X.5)),
    X=="C" ~ sum(c(X.3:X.56)))) %>% dplyr::select(Result_column)
```

Comment: Why `dbplyr`? There's no mention of databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `dplyr`>=1.0.0 using `rowSums()` (which computes the sum for a row across multiple columns) and `across()` (which superceded `vars()` as a method for specifying columns in a dataframe, allowing the use of `:` to select sequences of columns):

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(
  Result_column=case_when(
    X=="A"~ rowSums(across(X.1:X.5)),
    X=="B"~ rowSums(across(X.4:X.5)),
    X=="C" ~ rowSums(across(X.3:X.56))
    )
  ) %>% dplyr::select(Result_column)
```

Comment: You can remove `rowwise()`, it is not necessary (and almost always comes with a significant performance penalty).

Comment: @cnbrowlie i am receiving an error "Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs."  upon roundeding the numeric values to the thrid decimal place by using the following code "%>% dplyr::across(where(is.numeric), round, 3) ". I researched the internet and found an old post (https://statisticsglobe.com/r-error-must-only-be-used-inside-dplyr-verbs) using dplyr version <1.00 and it said to add the "dplyr::" prefix. I tried that and it threw the previous error "Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs." Do you know how to fix the error?

Comment: I'd need to know what was in front of the %>% pipe to know why you're getting the error but it tells you all you need to know, `dplyr::across` must be wrapped in a dplyr verb. In your original post and my answer it is wrapped in `mutate`. If you want to round numeric cols then you should add the `across` call from your comment into the mutate call from my answer: `mutate(Result_column=case_when(...), across(where()....))`

Comment: @cnbrowlie the following code was substituted, which worked "mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 3)"